# How do I convert multiple nested XML elements to a dataframe?

Tags: r, xml, xml2

I'm trying to convert an XML file into a dataframe in r ready to put into a CSV file.  Unfortunately I cannot seem to include the multiple lower levels.

A severely cut down version of this file is:

```
<Products Count="14790" >
<Product xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <FundCode>MyCompany</FundCode>
    <HospitalCover BasedOnID="">
        <HospitalTier>SilverPlus</HospitalTier>
        <Age Available="true" AvailableTransfer="true" />
        <MedicalServices>
            <MedicalService Title="Item1" Cover="Covered" />
            <MedicalService Title="Item2" Cover="NotCovered" />
        </MedicalServices>
    </HospitalCover>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

The code That has been most successful for me is below, but I don't know how to drill down into the xml to obtain the data from lower levels, currently it just groups the data from the next lower level into one column.

```
xmlfile <- xmlTreeParse("test_import.xml")
topxml <- xmlRoot(xmlfile)
head(topxml)
topxml <- xmlSApply(topxml,
                    function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))

xml_df <- data.frame(t(topxml),
                     row.names=NULL)
xml_df <- apply(xml_df,2,as.character)

write.csv(xml_df, "test_export.csv")
```

is the closest I've got to it

I've tried xpath to try and manually map columns to specific tags, but I also get no elements found

```
> a <- read_xml("test_import.xml")
> xml_find_all(a, xpath = "//Product")
{xml_nodeset (0)}
```

What I'd like to have is a dataframe along the lines of:

```
FundCode   HospitalTier   Age Available  AvailableTransfer   Item1     Item2
MyCompany  SilverPlus     True           True                Covered   NotCovered
```

Comment: Are you sure that XML is valid?

Comment: @thelatemail the "<Products Count="14790" >" part was on the same line as the three tildas, so it didn't show originally.  I've fixed that now

Comment: It still doesn't validate for me until I add a closing `</HospitalCover>` tag.

Comment: yes @thelateemail you were correct, it was missing the closing hospital tag, which I've fixed up now, thanks. This is a small example of the file to save space, that was my error, the file in question is a lot larger

Comment: Which elements repeat? *Product*? Usually XML samples should include enough to know the pattern. And always post the root tag as it may contain important namespaces.